# How To Encapsulate Multiple Fields in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I encapsulate multiple fields in Eclipse? Is there a way to select multiple fields in a "column", (like using the key combo CTRL + SHIFT) and then selecting "Encapsulate" from the context menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just position your mouse over the source code, right-click and select **Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...**

Eclipse will display its **Generate Getters and Setters** screen, listing all the fields that can be encapsulated. Just click the **Select All** button if you want to encapsulate everything, and then click **OK**. Alternatively, check individual getter/setter boxes if you need finer granularity:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was looking under "Refactor" instead of "Source".

Comment: You have my sympathy. You can position the cursor on a field and use Refactor -> Encapsulate Field... to encapsulate just one field, but have to use Source -> Generate Getters and Setters... to encapsulate multiple fields. Not a very intuitive interface.

Comment: Keep in mind that I don't think this will look for references outside of the current file. ie, if you're setting up a previously public field that is touched by other files to be private with getters/setters you'll need to use the refactor option.